# How order Customer Attributes?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, customer-attribute, sort, magento-enterprise-2

Magento 2 EE has customer attribute option, I want to know what are the segments and how add attributes to desired places ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Fully understand Customer attribute Segment option,you need to know about this feature:

As per definition of Customer Segment by Magento EE:

> Customer segments allow you to dynamically display content and
>   promotions to specific customers, based on properties such as customer
>   address, order history, shopping cart contents, and so on. You can
>   optimize marketing initiatives based on targeted segments by using
>   shopping cart price rules and banners. You can also generate reports
>   and export the list of targeted customers.
>
> Because customer segment information is dynamic and is constantly
>   refreshed, customers can become associated and disassociated from a
>   segment as they shop in your store.

To create customer segment go to link:

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/customers/customer-segment-create.html

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/customers/customer-segment-attributes.html

Comment: thinks for the support. Is this support checkout page attributes?

Comment: Yes,it is supported.you can select area where to show in attribute setting.